# How do I compute the brightness histogram aggregated by column in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram, ocr

I want to segment car plate to get separate characters.
I found some article, where such segmentation performed using brightness histograms (as i understand  - sum of all non-zero pixels).

[image]

How can i calculate such histogram? I would really appreciate for any help!

Comment: that's a simple [reduce()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce) (a projection of the image to either x or y axis)

Comment: @berak Which kind of output array would you have to pass when using CV_REDUCE_SUM?

Comment: an empty Mat. `Mat result; reduce(input, result,1,CV_REDUCE_SUM,CV_32S);`  (the output type should be larger than CV_8U in case you got more than 255 rows)

Comment: @berak Thanks! I would guess that, with sum, it's enough 2 rows to overflow! 255 rows is the limit if you use CV_16U. To sum by column I think "0" should be used, not "1".

Comment: ^^ oh, ofc. you're right. was just counting pixels in my head, not their sum.

Comment: also, to achieve the same pattern as above, you will have to invert it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> computeColumnHistogram(const cv::Mat& in) {

  std::vector<int> histogram(in.cols,0); //Create a zeroed histogram of the necessary size
  for (int y = 0; y < in.rows; y++) {
    p_row = in.ptr(y); ///Get a pointer to the y-th row of the image
    for (int x = 0; x < in.cols; x++)
      histogram[x] += p_row[x]; ///Update histogram value for this image column
  }

  //Normalize if you want (you'll get the average value per column): 
  //  for (int x = 0; x < in.cols; x++)
  //    histogram[x] /= in.rows;

  return histogram;

}
```

Or use [reduce](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce) as suggested by Berak, either calling

```
cv::reduce(in, out, 0, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
```

or

```
cv::reduce(in, out, 0, CV_REDUCE_SUM, CV_32S);
```

`out` is a `cv::Mat`, and it will have a single row.